# Transferring files from raspberry pi 3 Model B+ to raspberry pi zero v1

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, ssh, file-sharing, scp

I have a raspberry pi zero v1 and a raspberry pi model 3 B+. The second one has some testing files i want to transfer to the first one.

Right now i’m ssh’ed into both raspberry pi’s (I’ll call them rp’s for short). Rp Zero v1 doesn’t have Wi-Fi capabilities so I’m connected to the internet through the USB port in my PC, so i have accessed it via:

```
SSH pi@raspberrypi.local
```

And I’ve accessed the second one via:

```
SSH pi@<ip address>
```

Normally i use:

```
Scp <file> <path in original directory> <user I want to transfer to>:<path I want to transfer to>
```

To copy files from my pc to an rp, but I’m not sure what the user i want to transfer to is. I have tried

```
Scp <file> <original path> pi@raspberrypi.local:<destination path>
```

And

```
Scp <file> <original path> pi@<ip address>:<destination path>
```

Where `<ip address>` is what I obtained from running the command:

```
Hostname -I
```

On the rp zero v1.

Neither of these work and I think I may be missing some conceptual understanding of how the rp zero v1 is connected to the internet. I would appreciate some guidance to understand that as well as how to transfer files without having to first transfer something to my computer.

Comment: Scp usage: `scp [options] [local path] [remote path]`  The local path is just a normal path, don't use something like `me@here:/foobar`.  The remote path requires the remote user name (same as their login) and the hostname or IP: `me@there:/absolute/path`.  If it does not work, `scp -v` will output some debugging information, `scp -vv` more.  Edit it in the output from the latter with the exact command you are using and be aware of `man scp`.

Comment: You wrote "Neither of these work". How exactly does it not work? Do you get an error message? Then, please, copy&paste the exact command and the error message to your question. Or do you get a result different from what you expect? Then show/describe the actual and expected result in your question. [edit] your question to provide these details. Note that the `ssh` and `scp` commands are normally written with lowercase letters. On Windows it may be case-insensitive, but not on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ssh`, use `sftp`. Here's how it looks from the terminal:

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi3b:~ $ sftp pi@raspberrypi0w.local
The authenticity of host 'raspberrypi0w.local (192.168.1.51)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:AuR********************w9YDcZ0bijTO17zbeqvM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'raspberrypi0w.local,192.168.1.51' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
pi@raspberrypi0w.local's password:
Connected to raspberrypi0w.local.
sftp> ?
Available commands:
bye                                Quit sftp
cd path                            Change remote directory to 'path'
chgrp [-h] grp path                Change group of file 'path' to 'grp'
chmod [-h] mode path               Change permissions of file 'path' to 'mode'
chown [-h] own path                Change owner of file 'path' to 'own'
df [-hi] [path]                    Display statistics for current directory or
                                   filesystem containing 'path'
exit                               Quit sftp
get [-afpR] remote [local]         Download file
help                               Display this help text
lcd path                           Change local directory to 'path'
lls [ls-options [path]]            Display local directory listing
lmkdir path                        Create local directory
ln [-s] oldpath newpath            Link remote file (-s for symlink)
lpwd                               Print local working directory
ls [-1afhlnrSt] [path]             Display remote directory listing
lumask umask                       Set local umask to 'umask'
mkdir path                         Create remote directory
progress                           Toggle display of progress meter
put [-afpR] local [remote]         Upload file
pwd                                Display remote working directory
quit                               Quit sftp
reget [-fpR] remote [local]        Resume download file
rename oldpath newpath             Rename remote file
reput [-fpR] local [remote]        Resume upload file
rm path                            Delete remote file
rmdir path                         Remove remote directory
symlink oldpath newpath            Symlink remote file
version                            Show SFTP version
!command                           Execute 'command' in local shell
!                                  Escape to local shell
?                                  Synonym for help
sftp>
```

Once you get the `sftp>` prompt, type the `?` character to get a list of the commands & brief description of their meaning. The `get` & `put` commands perform the actual file transfers. See `man sftp` for more details; `exit` closes the connection.

And if you want to use SSH key authentication instead of passwords, [follow this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-2) to generate your public-private key pair & transfer the public key to the pi zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using internet connection sharing on the PC you can't.

You can turn ICS off (which will stop internet access) but then can ssh.

Incidentally ftp is a far easier way to transfer files and most PC have ftp clients.